# What distribution does a sampling proportion $\hat{p}$ of 0 have, if the Normal approximation does not work well away from $p=0.5$?

Tags: binomial-distribution, proportion, normality-assumption

I know that for sample proportions close to $0.5$, the normal approximation $\hat{p} \sim N(\hat{p}, \sqrt{\hat{p}*(1-\hat{p}) / n}$ can be used to estimate the distribution of this sample proportion. However, if I have a sample proportion of $0$ and a fairly large sample size of $n=90$, what would be the proper way to simulate sampling from its distribution? I've heard of the rule of 3, where $[0,3/n]$ is an approximation for the 95% confidence interval of the proportion, but am still unsure about how to use that information to simulate it since a normal distribution no longer works well against the lower bound.

Comment: You can use confidence intervals derived from inverted hypothesis tests.  The idea is that the confidence interval includes all values of the success probability for which your outcome (zero in your case zero) is not rejected

Comment: See [here](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~lbrown/Papers/2001a%20Interval%20estimation%20for%20a%20binomial%20proportion%20(with%20T.%20T.%20Cai%20and%20A.%20DasGupta).pdf) for a very interesting discussion